# Alfresco: Unable to CMIS query by path

Tags: alfresco

I am trying to find out the contents of a folder in Alfresco, using the following CMIS query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cmis:document 
WHERE CONTAINS('PATH:"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:GM/cm:emir/cm:FAQ//*"')
```

In **Node Browser**, if I navigate to that folder I see the following value for Primary Path

(I have added line breaks to make it easier to read):

```
/{http://www.alfresco.org/model/application/1.0}company_home
/{http://www.alfresco.org/model/site/1.0}sites
/{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}GM
/{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}EMIR
/{http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0}FAQ
```

But Alfresco is failing with the following message:

> Caused by: org.alfresco.scripts.ScriptException: 05120032 Failed to
>   execute script
>   'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/cmis/queries.post.cmisquery.js':
>   05120 031 Unknown column/property PATH

I am testing against Alfresco Community 3.3.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following query for simple search

```
SELECT * FROM cmis:document WHERE IN_FOLDER('id_of_folder')
```

or the following query for recursive search

```
SELECT * FROM cmis:document WHERE IN_TREE('id_of_folder').
```

if you want search by path, you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM cmis:folder 
WHERE CONTAINS('PATH:\"/app:company_home/st:sites/cm:my_site/cm:documentLibrary//*\"')
```

For more details view also the official specification

http://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/os/CMIS-v1.1-os.html

Answer (score 3):

Do yourself a favor and upgrade.

Your query works for me in the share node browser (does not throw exceptions) as either cmis-strict or cmis-alfresco .

```
SELECT * 
FROM cmis:document 
WHERE CONTAINS('PATH:"/app:company_home/st:sites//*"')
```

Gives me a whole lot of results.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that the query is fine. (Unfortunately the timing of my project's delivery, and the upgrade of Alfresco is beyond my control.)

Comment: I am worried about your project. IIRC, you mentioned you are building  on top of explorer instead of share, right ?  Good luck anyways.  ;)

Comment: I understand your concern :) TBH we are only creating a couple of custom types that are very simple. No workflows, one user, no versioning. We're using a tiny fraction of what Alfresco can do.