# Search document by node in Alfresco

Tags: search, alfresco, cmis

We need to create a query to find documents by node.

We have documents with the following properties:

```
<queryResponse>
<objects>
    <objects>
        <properties>
            <propertyBoolean propertyDefinitionId="cmis:isMajorVersion" localName="isMajorVersion" queryName="cmis:isMajorVersion">
                <s02:value>false
                </s02:value>
            </propertyBoolean>
            <propertyBoolean propertyDefinitionId="scs:doc_valido" localName="doc_valido" displayName="Válido" queryName="scs:doc_valido">
                <s02:value>true
                </s02:value>
            </propertyBoolean>
            <propertyBoolean propertyDefinitionId="cmis:isPrivateWorkingCopy" localName="isPrivateWorkingCopy" queryName="cmis:isPrivateWorkingCopy"/>
            <propertyBoolean propertyDefinitionId="cmis:isLatestMajorVersion" localName="isLatestMajorVersion" queryName="cmis:isLatestMajorVersion">
                <s02:value>false
                </s02:value>
            </propertyBoolean>
            <propertyBoolean propertyDefinitionId="cmis:isImmutable" localName="isImmutable" queryName="cmis:isImmutable">
                <s02:value>false
                </s02:value>
            </propertyBoolean>
            <propertyBoolean propertyDefinitionId="cmis:isLatestVersion" localName="isLatestVersion" queryName="cmis:isLatestVersion">
                <s02:value>true
                </s02:value>
            </propertyBoolean>
            <propertyBoolean propertyDefinitionId="cmis:isVersionSeriesCheckedOut" localName="isVersionSeriesCheckedOut" queryName="cmis:isVersionSeriesCheckedOut">
                <s02:value>false
                </s02:value>
            </propertyBoolean>
            <propertyBoolean propertyDefinitionId="inside:doc_origen" localName="doc_origen" displayName="Origen" queryName="inside:doc_origen">
                <s02:value>true
                </s02:value>
            </propertyBoolean>
            <propertyBoolean propertyDefinitionId="scs:es_revocado" localName="es_revocado" displayName="Consentimiento Revocado" queryName="scs:es_revocado"/>
            <propertyId propertyDefinitionId="alfcmis:nodeRef" localName="nodeRef" queryName="alfcmis:nodeRef">
                <s02:value>workspace://SpacesStore/d6988090-0475-44e0-b346-75041da3cd7b
                </s02:value>
            </propertyId>
            <propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectTypeId" localName="objectTypeId" queryName="cmis:objectTypeId">
                <s02:value>D:inside:documento
                </s02:value>
            </propertyId>
            <propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:baseTypeId" localName="baseTypeId" queryName="cmis:baseTypeId">
                <s02:value>cmis:document
                </s02:value>
            </propertyId>
            <propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:versionSeriesCheckedOutId" localName="versionSeriesCheckedOutId" queryName="cmis:versionSeriesCheckedOutId"/>
            <propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectId" localName="objectId" queryName="cmis:objectId">
                <s02:value>workspace://SpacesStore/d6988090-0475-44e0-b346-75041da3cd7b;1.1
                </s02:value>
            </propertyId>
            <propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:contentStreamId" localName="contentStreamId" queryName="cmis:contentStreamId">
                <s02:value>store://2019/11/28/15/50/53811130-6cb7-419b-afce-060249a17d0a.bin
                </s02:value>
            </propertyId>
            <propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:versionSeriesId" localName="versionSeriesId" queryName="cmis:versionSeriesId">
                <s02:value>workspace://SpacesStore/d6988090-0475-44e0-b346-75041da3cd7b
                </s02:value>
            </propertyId>
            <propertyInteger propertyDefinitionId="cmis:contentStreamLength" localName="contentStreamLength" queryName="cmis:contentStreamLength">
                <s02:value>15533
                </s02:value>
            </propertyInteger>
            <propertyDateTime propertyDefinitionId="cmis:creationDate" localName="creationDate" queryName="cmis:creationDate">
                <s02:value>2017-03-30T13:22:30.251Z
                </s02:value>
            </propertyDateTime>
            <propertyDateTime propertyDefinitionId="inside:doc_fechaCaptura" localName="doc_fechaCaptura" displayName="Fecha de Captura" queryName="inside:doc_fechaCaptura">
                <s02:value>2017-03-30T13:22:26.565Z
                </s02:value>
            </propertyDateTime>
            <propertyDateTime propertyDefinitionId="cmis:lastModificationDate" localName="lastModificationDate" queryName="cmis:lastModificationDate">
                <s02:value>2017-03-30T13:22:31.206Z
                </s02:value>
            </propertyDateTime>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="scs:doc_sexo" localName="doc_sexo" displayName="Sexo Paciente" queryName="scs:doc_sexo"/>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:description" localName="description" queryName="cmis:description"/>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:createdBy" localName="createdBy" queryName="cmis:createdBy">
                <s02:value>
                </s02:value>
            </propertyString>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="inside:doc_valorCSV" localName="doc_valorCSV" displayName="Valor CSV" queryName="inside:doc_valorCSV">
                <s02:value>0gN3S+P8f3GeUqDVLbp7Ch6LuxDXRenGl
                </s02:value>
            </propertyString>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="scs:doc_apellido1" localName="doc_apellido1" displayName="Primer Apellido Paciente" queryName="scs:doc_apellido1"/>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="scs:doc_apellido2" localName="doc_apellido2" displayName="Segundo Apellido Paciente" queryName="scs:doc_apellido2"/>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:contentStreamFileName" localName="contentStreamFileName" queryName="cmis:contentStreamFileName">
                <s02:value>ES_E00010207_2017_C1A890A28C4D38A2DEBB9B40FE9322.pdf
                </s02:value>
            </propertyString>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="scs:doc_nass" localName="doc_nass" displayName="NASS" queryName="scs:doc_nass">
                <s02:value>051999999971
                </s02:value>
            </propertyString>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="inside:doc_organo" localName="doc_organo" displayName="Organos" queryName="inside:doc_organo">
                <s02:value>E00010207
                </s02:value>
            </propertyString>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="scs:doc_dni" localName="doc_dni" displayName="DNI Paciente" queryName="scs:doc_dni"/>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="scs:id_doc_revocado" localName="id_doc_revocado" displayName="Identificado del Documento de Revocación" queryName="scs:id_doc_revocado"/>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="scs:doc_tamano" localName="doc_tamano" displayName="Tamano de la Digitalizacion" queryName="scs:doc_tamano"/>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="scs:doc_nombre" localName="doc_nombre" displayName="Nombre Paciente" queryName="scs:doc_nombre"/>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:contentStreamMimeType" localName="contentStreamMimeType" queryName="cmis:contentStreamMimeType">
                <s02:value>application/pdf
                </s02:value>
            </propertyString>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="inside:doc_identificadorDocOrigen" localName="doc_identificadorDocOrigen" displayName="Identificador Documento Origen" queryName="inside:doc_identificadorDocOrigen"/>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="scs:doc_fechaNacimiento" localName="doc_fechaNacimiento" displayName="Fecha de Nacimiento Paciente" queryName="scs:doc_fechaNacimiento"/>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="inside:doc_identificador" localName="doc_identificador" displayName="Identificador" queryName="inside:doc_identificador">
                <s02:value>ES_E00010207_2017_C1A890A28C4D38A2DEBB9B40FE9322
                </s02:value>
            </propertyString>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="inside:doc_versionNTI" localName="doc_versionNTI" displayName="Version NTI" queryName="inside:doc_versionNTI">
                <s02:value>
                </s02:value>
            </propertyString>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="inside:doc_tipoFirma" localName="doc_tipoFirma" displayName="Tipo de Firma" queryName="inside:doc_tipoFirma"/>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="scs:doc_sns" localName="doc_sns" displayName="SNS" queryName="scs:doc_sns"/>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="scs:doc_firma" localName="doc_firma" displayName="Valor Firma" queryName="scs:doc_firma">
                <s02:value>
                </s02:value>
            </propertyString>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="scs:doc_numHistoriaClinica" localName="doc_numHistoriaClinica" displayName="Numero de Historia Clinica" queryName="scs:doc_numHistoriaClinica">
                <s02:value>11645069
                </s02:value>
            </propertyString>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:versionLabel" localName="versionLabel" queryName="cmis:versionLabel">
                <s02:value>1.1
                </s02:value>
            </propertyString>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:checkinComment" localName="checkinComment" queryName="cmis:checkinComment"/>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="inside:doc_estadoElaboracion" localName="doc_estadoElaboracion" displayName="Estado de Elaboración" queryName="inside:doc_estadoElaboracion">
                <s02:value>EE99
                </s02:value>
            </propertyString>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:name" localName="name" queryName="cmis:name">
                <s02:value>ES_E00010207_2017_C1A890A28C4D38A2DEBB9B40FE9322.pdf
                </s02:value>
            </propertyString>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="scs:doc_numExpediente" localName="doc_numExpediente" displayName="Numero de Expediente" queryName="scs:doc_numExpediente">
                <s02:value>11645069
                </s02:value>
            </propertyString>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="inside:doc_tipoDocumental" localName="doc_tipoDocumental" displayName="Tipo Documental" queryName="inside:doc_tipoDocumental">
                <s02:value>TD02
                </s02:value>
            </propertyString>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="scs:doc_idioma" localName="doc_idioma" displayName="Idioma de la Digitalizacion" queryName="scs:doc_idioma"/>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:lastModifiedBy" localName="lastModifiedBy" queryName="cmis:lastModifiedBy">
                <s02:value>
                </s02:value>
            </propertyString>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="scs:doc_resolucion" localName="doc_resolucion" displayName="Resolucion de la Digitalizacion" queryName="scs:doc_resolucion"/>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="inside:doc_defGeneracionCSV" localName="doc_defGeneracionCSV" displayName="Definición Generación CSV" queryName="inside:doc_defGeneracionCSV"/>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:changeToken" localName="changeToken" queryName="cmis:changeToken"/>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="inside:doc_nombreFormato" localName="doc_nombreFormato" displayName="Nombre de Formato" queryName="inside:doc_nombreFormato">
                <s02:value>PDF
                </s02:value>
            </propertyString>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:versionSeriesCheckedOutBy" localName="versionSeriesCheckedOutBy" queryName="cmis:versionSeriesCheckedOutBy"/>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="scs:doc_certificado" localName="doc_certificado" displayName="Valor Certificado" queryName="scs:doc_certificado">
                <s02:value>
                </s02:value>
            </propertyString>
            <propertyString propertyDefinitionId="scs:valorCSV_revocado" localName="valorCSV_revocado" displayName="Valor CSV del Documento de Revocación" queryName="scs:valorCSV_revocado"/>
        </properties>
    </objects>
</objects>
```

We have tried to find it using the nodeRef query, as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM inside:documento WHERE alfcmis:nodeRef=1234
```

And the system responds to us:

Column refers to unqueryable property alfcmis:nodeRef

In addition we have also tried to use a real nodeRef value:

```
SELECT * FROM inside:documento WHERE alfcmis:nodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/d6988090-0475-44e0-b346-75041da3cd7b
```

However the system replies to us:

line 1:53 mismatched input 'workspace:' expecting COLON ([@12,53:62='workspace:',<37>,1:53]) in where
[query, whereClause, searchOrCondition, searchAndCondition, searchNotCondition, searchTest, predicate, comparisonPredicate, literalOrParameterName, parameterName, recoverFromMismatchedToken]

To solve the previous issue we have found that we maybe should use colon instead of equal sign:

https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/concepts/rm-searchsyntax-fields.html

So then, we wrote:

```
SELECT * FROM inside:documento WHERE alfcmis:nodeRef:workspace://SpacesStore/d6988090-0475-44e0-b346-75041da3cd7b
```

And the output is:

line 1:63 no viable alternative at character '/'

Due to the last exception we found that strings would need to be enclosed in single quotes '' and special characters be escaped with backslashes \

[Error in calling CMIS Query if String contains single or double quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34940423/error-in-calling-cmis-query-if-string-contains-single-or-double-quote)

Then we tried both approaches, first with single quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM inside:documento WHERE alfcmis:nodeRef:'workspace://SpacesStore/d6988090-0475-44e0-b346-75041da3cd7b'


SELECT * FROM inside:documento WHERE alfcmis:nodeRef:'workspace:\/\/SpacesStore\/d6988090-0475-44e0-b346-75041da3cd7b'
```

And the systems replies with:

1:53 no viable alternative at input ''workspace://SpacesStore/d6988090-0475-44e0-b346-75041da3cd7b\n''
(decision=28 state 66) decision=<<569:1: predicate : ( comparisonPredicate | inPredicate | likePredicate | nullPredicate | quantifiedComparisonPredicate | quantifiedInPredicate | textSearchPredicate | folderPredicate );>> in where
[query, whereClause, searchOrCondition, searchAndCondition, searchNotCondition, searchTest, predicate]

**EDIT**: As @Gagravarr writes, we have tested with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM inside:documento WHERE alfcmis:nodeRef='workspace://SpacesStore/d6988090-0475-44e0-b346-75041da3cd7b
```

'

So then the systems outputs:

Column refers to unqueryable property alfcmis:nodeRef

As well we have read:

https://docs.alfresco.com/6.1/concepts/dev-api-by-language-alf-rest-finding-content-by-search-query.html

https://docs.alfresco.com/6.1/concepts/dev-api-by-language-alf-rest-finding-content-by-term.html

https://docs.alfresco.com/6.1/concepts/dev-api-by-language-alf-rest-searching-for-nodes.html

https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/references/API-JS-findNode.html

[Alfresco: Unable to CMIS query by path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190975/alfresco-unable-to-cmis-query-by-path)

https://docs.alfresco.com/search-enterprise/concepts/searchsyntax-escaping.html

Comment: Shouldn't it be `SELECT * FROM inside:documento WHERE alfcmis:nodeRef = 'workspace://SpacesStore/d6988090-0475-44e0-b346-75041da3cd7b'` ? So `=` not `:` between the field and the value?

Comment: Take a look at [the answers on this somewhat related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671204/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-content-with-api-from-alfresco) and see if any of those help?

Comment: Also, if you have the noderef, why not just call the public REST API and grab back the properties on the document? No need to do a search if you already have the unique identifier that the other APIs require!